# Connecting to a named instance of SQL Server 2008 from classic ASP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

My ASP application connects to the network server where SQL Server 2000 is installed with no problem.  The old code that works:

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server};
              Server=myNetwrkServer;
              Database=myDB;
              UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=NO;")
```

An instance of SQL server 2008 was installed on the same network server.  The new code doesn't work:

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};
                      Server=myNetwrkServer\SQLServ2008;
                      Database=myDB;
                      UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection="NO";)
```

Please help!

Comment: I'm having big troubles with ASP Classic from a Win2003 server connecting over IP to a remote location with a non-default SQL-port. Wondering if the SQL2008 express needs to be updated (into R2) to work with ASP Classic or is the editions alike on this part?

Comment: I dont see a single answer showing me anything regarind none-default SQL-port for connection through WAN/IP. So I still cant mark anyone for the bounty as my problems hasnt been solved.

Answer (score 10):

Named instances require the [SQL Server Browser Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) to be enabled and started. If this service is not started on your `myNetwrkServer` machine then the connect from network will fail as they will not be able to resolve the instance name to an actual listening port.

A second problem is that you changed the driver to `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}`. This requires that you install the SQL Server 2008 native driver on your ASP machine. There is no reason to change the driver, you should leave the driver to the old `{SQL Server}` and let OleDB resolve the low level connecting driver for you. By specifying not only the native driver, but even the version number, you are dictating the low level connectivity stack and even if it would work, it would break at when you upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2. Just leave it at the generic `{SQL Server}` and let the driver manager figure out the details.

And finally, you need to make sure the login/password is defined on the new server.

As a generic rule, 'new code doesn't work' is never a something you should put in a request for help. Always put **how** it doesn't work. Do you get an exception, or an error? What exception, what message? Trying to help you doesn't have to be a mystery novel.

Answer (score 8):

You have mismatching quotes near the end of the line.

Should look like this

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};
                      Server=myNetwrkServer\SQLServ2008;
                      Database=myDB;
                      UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=NO;")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Trusted_Connection="NO";)
```

It looks like surrounding the value there with double quotes would throw things off.

Instead of:

```
("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myNetwrkServer\SQLServ2008;Database=myDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection="NO";)
```

It looks like you should have:

```
("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myNetwrkServer\SQLServ2008;Database=myDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=NO;")
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears your `Trusted_Connection` parameter is terminating the connection string improperly.

Consider removing the `Trusted_Connection` altogether, or ensuring that you don't put the NO in quotes.

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myNetwrkServer\SQLServ2008;
                Database=myDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=NO;")
```

Comment: Still missing a quote after the ;

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the quotes are mismatched. But, you shouldn't need the trusted connection bit. You either use `UID=` and `PWD=`, or `Trusted_Connection=yes`. You don't need all attributes at the same time.

This should work fine:

```
myConn.Open ("Driver=SQLNCLI10; 
              Server=myNetwrkServer\SQLServ2008; 
              Database=myDB; 
              UID=myID;
              PWD=myPWD;")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the checklist I go through when the connection to a new SQL Server fails from any network application (some points have already been mentioned):

1. Check if the SQL Server has ***SQL and Windows authentication*** enabled (default install option is Windows authentication only)
2. Check if the ***SQL Server Browser Service*** is enabled and running (default install option is not activated)
3. Check if ***TCP/IP connections*** are enabled for your SQL Server instance (default is usually disabled)
4. Check if the ***server firewall*** allows connections to the SQL Server and SQL Server Browser (newly, this is often an issue)
5. Check if the ***database user*** defined in your database also exists on the new SQL Server with same login credentials
6. Check if the ***database user*** has the according ***access rights*** on your database if you moved your database from another server to the new one
7. And last but not least, check your ***application database configuration*** if it is really doing what you expect (this should probably go first)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Eton B and Remus Rusanu said, you should also check that the Named Pipes protocol is enabled on the SQL Server. To check (on the server):

1. (Programs in the Start menu)
2. (Microsoft SQL Server 2008/Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2)
3. SQL Server Configuration Manager
4. Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
5. (Select Protocols for ). This will list the protocols and whether they are enabled.

If Named Pipes is not enabled, right-click, Properties, change `Enabled` to `Yes`.

Another choice is to force tcp (obviously use similar steps as above to verify that tcp is enabled). You can force tcp by changing your connection string so that you prefix your server name with `tcp:`:

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server};
              Server=tcp:myNetwrkServer;
              Database=myDB;
              UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=NO;")
```

If you force tcp, also take note that by default your application will access the database on port 1433 which means that port needs to be open on the server if that server is running a firewall.