# Connecting from classic ASP app to an instance of SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

My classic ASP app is connecting to SQL server 2000 installed on a network server. The current code works:

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server};Server=myNetServ;Database=myDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=No;")
```

Now my app needs to connect to a named instance "SQL2008" of the SQL server 2008 installed on the same network server.  This code doesn't work:

```
myConn.Open ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myNetServ\SQL2008;Database=myDB;UID=myID;PWD=myPWD;Trusted_Connection=No;")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to a named instance of SQL Server 2008 from classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418203/connecting-to-a-named-instance-of-sql-server-2008-from-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0):

you could just build an odbc connection and use that to connect to the instance